# How to install Ubuntu touch on a tablet?

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-touch

i have a Galaxy Tab 3 7.0 and i want to install Ubuntu Touch on it, someone can help me?

I looked at the specs of Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 and they have the same specs, even the resolution (600x1024), can I install Ubuntu for GT2 7.0 on my GT3 7.0?

Comment: See http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=836022

Answer (score 0):

These are two different devices, with different motherboards and supporting chipsets. What you are attempting is NOT recommended, and will likely 'brick' (or render useless) your device.

---

GALAXY Tab 2 7.0 vs. Tab 3 7.0 (specifications)

http://gadgetstouse.com/news/samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7-0-vs-samsung-galaxy-tab-3-7-0-specifications-comparison/7631